# Android wrap_content too wide when centred text of TextView is long

Tags: android, android-layout, text-alignment, layout-gravity

You can use either `layout_gravity` or `gravity` for text centring. With `layout_gravity`:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:breakStrategy="balanced"
/>
```

Short stretches of text will be displayed as:

```
[          Hello          ]
```

While long stretches will be: (*A*)

```
[ One lemming looking     ]
[ up.                     ]
```

So you might add:

```
    android:gravity="center"
```

And you'll get: (*B*)

```
[   One lemming looking   ]
[           up.           ]
```

However, I want to achieve this: (*C*)

```
[   One lemming looking   ]
[   up.                   ]
```

*A* does not look good, because text does not appear centred. This is especially true if there are more centred elements in the layout.

*B* does not look good, because the very short word "up" was put into the centre. Even if the text is longer, it doesn't look good, because the text has two jagged edges (left + right) instead of just one (to the right).

*C* is the same as *A*, but correctly centred. The reason why *A* does not look centred is because `wrap_content` assumes the width of the TextView is as wide as the parent's when the text wraps on another line, and does not compute the *actual* width of the block of text.

So, how do I achieve *C*? Is it possible?

Here's the full layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/primary_form"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
    android:textColor="@color/text_primary_on_lt"
    android:breakStrategy="balanced"
    tools:text="Primary form adfahdkahdfa "
/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/secondary_form"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
    android:textColor="@color/text_secondary_on_lt"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:breakStrategy="balanced"
    tools:text="Secondary form"
/>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: IMO, Simplest way to achieve this is to put all textviews with "left" tag in vertical linear layout which has "centre" tag and "wrap_content" width.

Comment: OK, I'm going to try that.

Comment: @Dexter Hm, no, doesn't work. My TextViews actually are inside a LinearLayout already. What you'll get is (A).

Comment: simply use left or/and right padding

Comment: @pskink: I can't use fixed padding, because I don't know the text's length, so the padding might be a waste of available space.

Comment: Can you provide full xml (at least TextView part)? from current data, I am not able to visualize your UI.

Comment: so why do you want "3 space" padding on the left and on the right? (picture C) why it is 3 spaces, why not 4 or 5?

Comment: @pskink: I want the textview to centre texts that occupy a single line only, while having the textview left-align longer texts, but the textview itself is to be centred.

Comment: @Dexter: I've added the full layout

Comment: but in C the text "One lemming looking up" could fit one line, so why two lines?

Comment: @pskink: No, it doesn't fit, but the character-based example might not visualize it well enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this in multiple ways, but I will show you two ways, First with old school linear layouts

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/primary_form"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:breakStrategy="balanced"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            tools:text="Primary form adfahdkahdfa " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/secondary_form"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:breakStrategy="balanced"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:typeface="serif"
            tools:text="Secondary form" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now with latest constraint layout. This is more robust and recommended way. Assuming you want your primary text in middle and secondary text just below it,

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:breakStrategy="balanced"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline16"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:text="Primary form adfahdkahdfa " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondary_form"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:breakStrategy="balanced"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:typeface="serif"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline16"
        tools:text="Secondary form" />


    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline16"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.50793654"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="288dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/secondary_form" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: Ah, I see. Double nesting. Not very elegant, but seems to work! Thanks!

Comment: Hm, no doesn't work, I'm afraid. Texts are no longer centred. primary_form and secondary_form should act independently, too.

Comment: After playing around a bit, my conclusion is that your solution is better than what I actually wanted to achieve. :)

Comment: @digorydoo : in case you don't want nested linear layouts. I have updated answer :)

Comment: Thanks. I already did something similar with a RelativeLayout instead of a ConstraintLayout.